# Recursive function for returning the shortest combined String of 2 given strings

Tags: java, string, recursion

I've problems running my method. The method should return the smallest smallest possible String that contains both given Strings by the user, so for example if String 1 is 'A' and String 2 is 'AA', the method should return 'AA'. If String 1 is 'AGGTAB' and String 2 is 'GXTXAYB' then the smallest String that the method should return is 'AGXGTXAYB'.
The function has to return the new combined String in the order of the original Strings, so for example 'ABCDE' does not include 'ADB', but it does include 'ABD' and 'BCE'.
This is my written function so far:

````
   ```
public class m
{
    public static String minimalSt(String s1, String s2) {
        String lcs = longestCommonString (s1,s2);
        return minimalSt (s1, 0, s2, 0, lcs, 0, "");
    }
    
    public static String minimalSt (String s1, int ai, String s2, int bi, String lcs, int lcsi, String result) {
        System.out.println(result);
        boolean isA = s1.length()>ai;
        boolean addA = isA;
        boolean isB = s2.length()>bi;
        boolean addB = isB;
        boolean isLcs = lcs.length()>lcsi;
        boolean addLcs = false;
        if (isA && isB)
            if (s1.charAt(ai) == lcs.charAt(lcsi))
                addA = false;
        if (s2.charAt(bi) == lcs.charAt(lcsi))
            addB = false;
        if (!addA && !addB && isLcs)
            addLcs = true;
        if (addLcs)
            return minimalSt (s1, ai+1, s2, bi+1, lcs, lcsi+1, result+lcs.charAt(lcsi));
        else if (addA && addB)
            return minimalSt (s1, ai+1, s2, bi+1,lcs,lcsi,result+s1.charAt(ai)+s2.charAt(bi));
        else if (addA)
            return minimalSt (s1, ai+1, s2, bi, lcs, lcsi, result+s1.charAt(ai));
        else if (addB)
            return minimalSt (s1, ai, s2, bi+1, lcs,lcsi, result+s2.charAt(bi));
        return result;
    }
    
    public static String longestCommonString (String s1, String s2) 
    {
        int alength = s1.length()-1;
        int blength = s2.length()-1;
        if (alength < 0 || blength <0)
            return " ";
        if (s1.substring(alength).equals(s2.substring(blength)))
        { 
            return longestCommonString(s1.substring(0, alength), s2.substring (0, blength)) + s1.substring(alength);
        }
        else
        {
            String first = longestCommonString (s1, s2.substring(0,blength));
            String second = longestCommonString (s1.substring(0,alength),s2);
            if (first.length()>second.length()) {
                return first;
            } else
                return second;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(minimalSt("AGGTAB", "GXTXAYB"));
    }

}
 ```
````

Something doesn't seem to work. Please, if you wish to help me I'm grateful, but please don't write your own code but tell me what's wrong with mine or rewrite mine if you do decide to write one. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can't see, how the combination of 'AGGTAB' and  'GXTXAYB' would result in  'AGXGTXAYB', since the result is just the second string with prefix AGX, which is not part of the first string.

Comment: @juwil 'AGXGTXAYB' contains 'AGGTAB', in the same order that the latter is written, just with extra letters in-between, which is fine. The combination can contain letters that don't appear in one of the 2 strings, but has to contain both of the strings with the exact same order that they are written.  A more simple example is 'ABCD' that contains 'AD' and 'BD' but doesn't contain 'CA' or 'DB'.

Comment: You say that something doesnt seem to be working. Could you please tell us what this is?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are only four cases:

1. `s1(ai) == s3(ci) && s2(bi) == s3(ci)` then, `res += s3(ci), ai++, bi++, ci++`
2. `s1(ai) == s3(ci) && s2(bi) != s3(ci)` then, `res += s2(bi), bi++`
3. `s1(ai) != s3(ci) && s2(bi) == s3(ci)` then, `res += s1(ai), ai++`
4. `s1(ai) != s3(ci) && s2(bi) != s3(ci)` then, `res += s2(bi) + s1(ai), ai++, bi++`

where

- s1 - First string // AGGTAB
- s2 - Second string // GXTXAYB
- s3 - Longest common string // GTAB

so the final version is as follows:

```
public class m {
    public static String minimalSt(String s1, String s2) {
        String lcs = longestCommonString(s1, s2);
        return minimalSt(s1, 0, s2, 0, lcs, 0, "");
    }

    public static String minimalSt(String s1, int ai, String s2, int bi, String lcs, int lcsi, String result) {
//        System.out.println(result);
        boolean isA = s1.length() > ai;
        boolean addA = isA;
        boolean isB = s2.length() > bi;
        boolean addB = isB;
        boolean isLcs = lcs.length() > lcsi;
        if (isA && isLcs && s1.charAt(ai) == lcs.charAt(lcsi))
            addA = false;
        if (isB && isLcs && s2.charAt(bi) == lcs.charAt(lcsi))
            addB = false;
        if (isLcs && !addA && !addB)
            return minimalSt(s1, ai + 1, s2, bi + 1, lcs, lcsi + 1, result + lcs.charAt(lcsi));
        else if (!addA && addB)
            return minimalSt(s1, ai, s2, bi + 1, lcs, lcsi, result + s2.charAt(bi));
        else if (!addB && addA)
            return minimalSt(s1, ai + 1, s2, bi, lcs, lcsi, result + s1.charAt(ai));
        else if (addA && addB)
            return minimalSt(s1, ai + 1, s2, bi + 1, lcs, lcsi, result + s2.charAt(bi) + s1.charAt(ai));
        return result;
    }

    public static String longestCommonString(String s1, String s2) {
        int alength = s1.length() - 1;
        int blength = s2.length() - 1;
        if (alength < 0 || blength < 0)
            return ""; // <- changed this line
        if (s1.substring(alength).equals(s2.substring(blength))) {
            return longestCommonString(s1.substring(0, alength), s2.substring(0, blength)) + s1.substring(alength);
        } else {
            String first = longestCommonString(s1, s2.substring(0, blength));
            String second = longestCommonString(s1.substring(0, alength), s2);
            if (first.length() > second.length()) {
                return first;
            } else
                return second;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(minimalSt("AGGTAB", "GXTXAYB"));
        System.out.println(minimalSt("AGGTAB", "HDS"));
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all I thank your efforts, really do! 
In your method, you don't need the longestCommonString? or I got that wrong and you do use it?

Comment: Also, sorry for not stating it before and confusing you, but I'm not allowed to use trim() in this challenge that I took, is there a way to run the method without it?

Comment: Sorry for triple posting, it won't let me edit the comments. I deleted the .trim() method from the minimalSt call, and also deleted the space bar in the longestCommonString method inside the "", it works fine, but only for strings that contain each other, so for Zhuragat Bolakhan it returns:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
 at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
 at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
Any clue?